# Can I pass a list of column names into get_dummies() to use as the column label for all possible answers?

Tags: python, pandas

(EDITED:  I just realised I think I am asking a question that cannot be answered but not sure how to delete this question... please ignore or advise on how I can delete.  I think I need to think about a different way to approach this problem.)

******----------------------------*****

I have a DataFrame called user_answers, this DataFrame is formed using get_dummies().  It looks like this

> Index,Q1_1,Q1_2,Q1_4,Q1_5,mas_Y,fhae_Y
>
> 1,1,0,0,0,0,0
>
> 2,0,0,1,0,1,0
>
> 3,0,1,0,0,1,1
>
> 4,1,0,0,0,1,0
>
> 5,0,0,0,1,1,0
>
> 6,0,0,1,0,1,1
>
> 7,0,1,0,0,1,1

I am needing to do a comparison against a similar DataFrame called DF_answers.  That DataFrame looks like this

> Index,Q1_1,Q1_2,Q1_3,Q1_4,Q1_5,mas_Y,fhae_Y
>
> 1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0
>
> 2,1,0,0,0,0,1,0
>
> 3,0,1,0,0,0,1,1
>
> 4,0,0,1,0,0,1,0
>
> 5,0,0,0,0,1,1,0
>
> 6,1,0,0,0,0,1,1
>
> 7,0,0,0,1,0,1,1

The problem I am having is when I use 'get_dummies' does not create a column in the user_answers dataframe for Q1_3 assuming that the user didn't select Q1_3 as an answer in any of the 7 questions in the original questionnaire.  I need to try get my output of user_answers to look like this.  So even if the user did not answer Q1_3 on any of the 7 questions the get_dummies will still output a column Q1_3 filled with zeros as per illustration below.

> Index,Q1_1,Q1_2,**Q1_3**,Q1_4,Q1_5,mas_Y,fhae_Y
>
> 1,1,0,0,0,**0**,0,0
>
> 2,1,0,0,0,**0**,1,0
>
> 3,0,1,0,0,**0**,1,1
>
> 4,1,0,0,0,**0**,1,0
>
> 5,0,0,0,1,**0**,1,0
>
> 6,1,0,0,0,**0**,1,1
>
> 7,1,0,0,0,**0**,1,1

I think I have over thought this so much im possibly over thinking things.  I read that you can pass in a list of column names into get_dummies()

Comment: so, if I understand correctly, you need to create a blank data frame with every possible user ID, and every column that has been answered, you then will merge your df and blanks with will be filled with a value of your choosing ? also down voter should atleast explain why they downvoted.

Comment: can you post your expected output too?

Comment: Sorry, I read through my question again and realised I wasn't very clear. Please give me a moment to revise.

Comment: Got it, it's clear now. Will have a look once I'm back at laptop.

Comment: @Datanovice sorry I had already edited my whole question before I saw your response and then after editing realised I might be asking something that isn't possible in get_dummies().  I might have to add a fake question 8 with all possible answers used to force the get_dummies to detect the missing columns and somehow subtract or remove the fake data from the get_dummies() dataframe called user_answers

Comment: no worries, does the user have a unique ID? and do you know the number of max questions?

Comment: yes and there are 100 questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the delay,

find my attempt below:

from what I understand the following applies

1. You have a dataframe which only has questions which the user filled out.
2. you need to merge this onto a frame which has every question for some sort of further anaylsis?

if this is true this is my noobish attempt:

```
cols = ['ID','Q1_1','Q1_2','Q1_4','Q1_5','mas_Y','fhae_Y']
data = []
for x in enumerate(cols):
    data.append(np.random.randint(0,150,size=150))
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(cols,data)))
print(df.head())
    ID  Q1_1    Q1_2    Q1_4    Q1_5    mas_Y   fhae_Y
0   7   76  41  46  57  75  139
1   11  118 65  38  17  116 75
2   111 104 109 110 32  53  106
3   131 14  92  128 14  22  65
4   83  72  148 99  103 133 144

## Create a dummy frame
cols_b = ['ID'] 
x = 0
for i in range(1,101):
    cols_b.append('Q1_' + str(x+i))

data_b = []
for x in enumerate(cols_b):
    data_b.append(np.nan)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(cols_b,data_b)),index=[0])
final_cols = list(df2.columns)
final_cols.append('fhae_Y')
final_cols.append('mas_Y')
df = pd.merge(df,df2,how='left')
print(df[final_cols].fillna(0).head(5))
    ID  Q1_1    Q1_2    Q1_3    Q1_4    Q1_5    Q1_6    Q1_7    Q1_8    Q1_9    ... Q1_93   Q1_94   Q1_95   Q1_96   Q1_97   Q1_98   Q1_99   Q1_100  fhae_Y  mas_Y
0   7   76  41  0.0 46  57  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 139 75
1   11  118 65  0.0 38  17  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 75  116
2   111 104 109 0.0 110 32  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 106 53
3   131 14  92  0.0 128 14  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 65  22
4   83  72  148 0.0 99  103 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 144
```

Comment: Thanks @Datanovice, I just sat down at my desk after being away.  Im super grateful for your answer.  I am about to go through it now, bare with me while I go through it.  Im a bit slow as im quite a noob still. Much appreciated.

Comment: if you need additional help, let me know.

Comment: Thanks I just wanted to get back to you, I don't think I explained my question very clearly.  Your answer does look correct, Im just not sure how to correctly use it in my existing code.  What I ended up doing is created new dataframe called DF_template, I added all the possible answers to that dataframe and appended to the target DF before passing it into get_dummies().  After it generated the results I removed the appended data using df.drop(df.tail(5).index, inplace=True).  This gave me the desired output.  I am going to mark it as complete and really appreciate your input.

Comment: Instead of append why not use pd.merge()? This allows for a cleaner way of merge two frames. Glad I could help :)